# How to display latest unique record in mysql codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, unique, distinct

**lets suppose i have 6 records in my table**

```
    id |       mobile_no  |     date
-------------------------------------------        
    1  |       9999999999 |   11-11-2016

    2  |       8888888888 |   12-11-2016

    3  |       9999999999 |   13-11-2016

    4  |       9999999999 |   16-11-2016

    5  |       8888888888 |   20-11-2016

    6  |       8888888888 |   22-11-2016
```

**Now when i use distinct with mysql query i retrieve :-**

```
    id |       mobile_no  |     date
-------------------------------------------    
    1  |       9999999999 |   11-11-2016

    2  |       8888888888 |   12-11-2016
```

**While i want to retrieve :-**

```
    id |       mobile_no  |     date
-------------------------------------------    
    4  |       9999999999 |   16-11-2016

    6  |       8888888888 |   22-11-2016
```

Please help me what query i have to use in codeigniter mysql for access above records??

below is my model query -

```
    $this->db->select('*');

     $this->db->from('miscall_records'); 

    $this->db->distinct(); 

    $this->db->group_by('mobnos');

     $this->db->order_by("id", "desc");
```

Comment: well - could you **include** the query in question? i'm afraid i can't telepathically debug.

Comment: not as a comment. **edit** your question to include additional information

Comment: Not sure how it could be done on CI but the sql should be of the pattern as in the document here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html

Comment: be adviced: `GROUP BY` does **not in any way** make any guarantees about which datasets are returned - it should **always** be used in combination with aggregation functions. in your case, `DISTINCT` has nothing to do with it.

Comment: it simple use MAX(date) while fetching the record

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use the dataset with the highest ID each, you have to use a different approach.
you have to select the highest IDs for each number first via a `GROUP BY` with the corresponding aggregation function `MAX`, and then join the table itself on those keys.

```
SELECT values.* FROM
(SELECT MAX(id) AS id FROM miscall_records GROUP BY mobile_no) AS keys
LEFT JOIN miscall_records AS values
ON keys.id = values.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Your expected sql query is :

```
select a.id, a.mobile_no, a.date from miscall_records a
where a.id = (select max(b.id) from miscall_records b 
where b.mobile_no = a.mobile_no) group by a.mobile_no
```

With Active Records is :

```
$this->db->select('a.id, a.mobile_no, a.date');
$this->db->from('miscall_records a');
$this->db->where('a.id = (select max(b.id) from miscall_records b where b.mobile_no = a.mobile_no)'); 
$this->db->group_by('a.mobile_no');    
$query = $this->db->get();
```

---

Or use only `max` :

```
select max(a.id), a.mobile_no, a.date from miscall_records a group by a.mobile_no
```

Active records :

```
$this->db->select('max(a.id), a.mobile_no, a.date');
$this->db->from('miscall_records a'); 
$this->db->group_by('a.mobile_no');    
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use group by clause to group values by mobile no. distinct keyword will not work here.